# How to add figures in separate files and not embed in LaTeX

Tags: floats

I submitted an article to JISA which follows the BioMed Central's TeX template. The editor gave me corrections regarding the LaTeX format. One of the instruction is,

*Figures should be provided as separate files, not embedded in the main manuscript file.*

I used `\includegraphics` command for the figures. How can I not embed figures in LaTeX and still provide it in final output?

Comment: Send them the files along with the texfile.

Comment: And comment out (`%`) the lines with `\includegraphics`. Then they are not embedded in the manuscript, but their locations can later be found easily.

Comment: I guess that the editor complain only of the floats within the text. Anyway, the  point is that the author do not have to provide the final output but,  only the contents as the editor asks. Traditionally, many editors want only text,  with captions and images in another file/s, because is a lot easier construct the article  layout that reconstruct it from a  frightening doc,odt, rtf...  with  embedded  images.  I suppose that actually this is a little problem when the format is LateX and specially when it is your own template, but you know: tradition is law.